# Including Droid-Fu library in Android project

Tags: java, android, buildpath

I opted to compile my Android project against the Droid-Fu source rather than packaging the library into a JAR. Thus, I imported Droid-Fu into my workspace and added it as an Android library to my project.

I'm currently using the `WebImageView` widget. My code compiles with no problems, but when I run the app I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.droidfu.widgets.WebImageView...
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but I have included the DroidFu library in Order and Export for my project's build path.

Obviously the library is included in my build path, so why is it not being found at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well it looks like all I needed to do was include the library's source in the project build path (using Link Source) rather than include the library as a project dependence.